# restlet client side POST request with header and JSON

Tags: json, post, header, restlet

Could you please comment what wrong with this client side restlet code.

It is necessary:

1. Add HTTP header `X-MF-Auth-Token` with value token
2. Place JSON file to the body of HTTP request
3. Make POST request to server

Post request generates "400" error. Thank you very much!

```
        ClientResource cr = new ClientResource(servername + "/json/place");

        cr.getRequest().getAttributes().put("X-MF-Auth-Token", token);

        Form form = new Form ();

        form.add("Category", "");
        form.add("CategoryId", "A1EECAB9-3E66-4F14-92E9-465EDFB22BA7");
        form.add("Latitude", "0");
        form.add("Longitude", "0"); 
        form.add("Name", "Loremipsum");
        form.add("PlaceId", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000099");

    cr.post(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    if (cr.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
        // Register Successful
        Log.v("Register()", "Successeful");
        return true;
    } else {
        Log.v("Register()", "ERROR");
        return false;
    }

    } catch (ResourceException e) {
        // Login Error
    Log.v("AddPlace() error:", e.getStatus().toString());
    return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSONObject instead of Form:

```java
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
try {
     jo.add("Category", "");
     jo.add("CategoryId", "A1EECAB9-3E66-4F14-92E9-465EDFB22BA7");
     jo.add("Latitude", "0");
     jo.add("Longitude", "0"); 
     jo.add("Name", "Loremipsum");
     jo.add("PlaceId", "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000099");
} catch (JSONException ex) {          
}
cr.post(new JsonRepresentation(jo), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you're **not** adding `X-MF-Auth-Token` to the header.

try

```
Form headers = (Form) cr.getRequest().getAttributes("org.restlet.http.headers");
if (headers == null) {
    headers = new Form();
    cr.getRequest().getAttributes.put("org.restlet.http.headers", headers);
}
headers.add("X-MF-Auth-Token", token);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful, but still doesn't work. It is necessary to set Content-Type to JSON, but it sends Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Comment: @mfirry That link talks about using RESTlet server-side and doesn't describe anything about the client-side.  What the OP was asking for was client-side.

Comment: Although it is a long time ago but the Form defaults the request to be of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded. Sending JSON requires a different datatype.